# Node-red dashboard audio-out node does not play on raspberry pi

Tags: dashboard, node-red, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to play TTS on the node-red dashboard. Luckily I thought there's the Audio Out node, where you feed a string in, some TTS service converts it to audio and then it's played via the browser you opened the dashboard UI.

Which works fine on my pc while trying, but not on raspberry pi chromium in kiosk mode... There it only prints a notification box which states the text it was supposed to speak...

Anybody ran into this issue?

I have node red installed on docker on RPI3B+ 1, and RPI3 2 with touchscreen as the UI running chromium in kiosk mode.

Chromium plays audio (tested with youtoube) well... so that's not the issue.

**Edit**

Seems like audio out is trying to do speech synthesis in the browser, but chromium doesn't show providers?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok easy solution:
Use node-red-contrib-google-tts to get an URL to tts output, feed it through msg.url into a http request nice with binary payload and feed this to the audio out node... And here we go